# EMI Filter - current in inductors / part selection

Tags: inductor, emc, led-driver, constant-current, emi-filtering

I want to use a [NLDD-1400H LED Driver](https://www.meanwellusa.com/upload/pdf/NLDD-H/NLDD-H-spec.pdf) as constant current source with 1.4A ouput. On the last page of the datasheet there are information about an EMI Filter, I want to use. Here is the schematic:

[image: NLDD EMI Filter]

Now I started looking for according parts but I have a problem regarding the current rating of the inductors - if I take the first inductor (1.5mH) for example - I can find a lot of inductors which can handle some mA but not the 1.4A I will use the LED driver.

Do I have a wrong understanding that I need a inductor fulfilling 1.4A as max. current or is this assumption right and I just need to search more?

Comment: 15 mH is quite a large inductance. Is that really what you need? As the number of turns scale with inductance, and the conductor cross-section with the current, a high-current high-inductance coil is much larger, heavier, costlier than a large-current, lower-inductance one.

Comment: my guess is you're hence looking at the wrong category of components: you want common-mode chokes, probably, but might be looking at fixed inductors. Which category of components (link?) have you been looking at?

Comment: It's 1.5mH, not 15mH. The hint with the common-mode Chokes is good I will have a look at this.

Comment: But the main question is, is it at all right to assume the inductor will "see" the 1.4 A that will be drawn by the driver, considering it being parallel to the driver, not in series?

Comment: I just added the schematic of the EMI Filter in the original question, should make it more clear

Comment: again, please link to the category of articles you've been looking at. 1.5mH is still a lot for 1.4 A inductor.

Comment: Ok, I was looking here for example: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/fixed-inductors/71

Comment: And best would be if I can use something from here: https://jlcpcb.com/parts

Comment: Daniel, look at the [common-mode chokes category](https://www.digikey.com/short/52c12c5j)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the link. These parts are huge :/ Now I wonder again, am I really looking for current values which will flow through the LED driver, considering the parts are in parallel to the driver. How can I calculate which current will flow in the inductors?